# NTLM Authentication Protocol with APEX

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, authentication

I'm working on a project requires integration between Salesforce and Microsoft Navision with NTLM authentication.

As I see people refer to NTLM authencation implementation [ApexNTLM](https://github.com/natewallace/ApexNTLM) but it doesn't work for me. I get 401 status code.

The credentials are valid because I'm able to get proper results with browser, SOAP UI and Insomnia (Postman's NTLM authentication is broken).

So, I'm looking a way to handle this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks (+100 Bounty Points added)

Comment: Are you doing it via delegated authentication?

Comment: Hi David, not via delegated auth.

Comment: I think I had misunderstood your post. What you're doing it's trying to integrate with a service that uses NTLM auth, right?

Comment: Hi David. Yes, I'm trying to integrate with Microsoft Navision OData REST service based on NTLM authentication.

Comment: @FıratEsmer [This](https://github.com/natewallace/ApexNTLM/issues/5) seems to be a similar issue reported on the github repo. did you try to contact the contributors of the repo ?

Comment: @Shamina I did not because repo seems dead to me.